# gcloud functions deploy issue

Tags: function, gcloud

I try to deploy one gcloud function with the below Github link to back up the datastore.

https://github.com/portsoc/cloud-simple-datastore-backup/blob/master/index.js

After updating the variant BUCKET_NAME with my cloud storage bucket name, I run it under gcloud shell with the command: **node index.js** and it will backup the datastore successfully.

but when I continue to run the below command to deploy it:

**gcloud functions deploy main 

--runtime nodejs12 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated 

--region=asia-southeast2**

After a while, it will give me the below error:

**Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.

**ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.****
[Click to view the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etk5L.png)

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions have a specific set of signatures that must be used.

I'm less familiar with JavaScript|Node.JS but I think the function you reference is intended to be invoked as you do `node index.js` (or similar) and this is incompatible with Cloud Functions.

Please review [Write Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing) to understand that signature type that you will need. You will probably have to tweak the authentication in the example to better meet your needs too.

Almost certainly you don't want `--allow-unauthenticated` either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I believe the type of cloud function is HTTP.
I also try to remove the --allow-unauthenticated, but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the upload code below, I can deploy it.

```
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

// fill in your bucket name here:
const BUCKET_NAME = "gs://testinbbk10";


exports.myfunction = async (req,res) =>{
  try {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    console.log(`Project ID is ${projectId}`);

    const res2 = await client.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}:export`,
      data: {
        outputUrlPrefix: BUCKET_NAME,
      },
    });
    console.error("RESPONSE:");
    console.log(res2.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ERROR");
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

**but when I try to access the provided link: [deploy link](https://asia-southeast2-my-project-cloudfunctionbackup.cloudfunctions.net/function002), it will show me the error: could not handle the request.**

I am confused about how to properly deploy this to the google cloud function? Just want to deploy one simply google cloud function to backup datastore in the google cloud.